# How are Outbound Call Rates calculated

Tags: twilio

How are outbound call rates calculated? Is there an API we can Query?

On Twilio Website I can pick "making calls from Canada -> [Select a country]" but if I'm asking Twilio to initiate a call, how does it work?

Is it assuming my calls are all initiated from Canada (because of my account's origin)?

Is it a flat rate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about an API query, but they do have csv files that contain the voice pricing. I upload the csv files into my application so that I can determine the costs myself. You can though use the usage api, which will allow you to get the costs after the call, though I prefer being able to calculate the costs server side as well.

they charge for each leg of a call, so if you are using the Twilio client to call a mobile number for example, you will be charged for the outbound leg of the client and also the leg to the mobile number. I believe the client leg price is a flat rate, at this moment you can see the client pricing here, https://www.twilio.com/client/pricing, after that you will add the number price, in your case Canada, pricing can be found here, https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing/ca

I believe this would be a starting point at the current prices, for a 1 minute call using the Twilio client to a Canada local number.
Client => $ 0.0025
Local Number => $ 0.015
Total (1 minute) -> $ 0.0175

The billing is also per minute, so they will always round up to the nearest minute, https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-you-round-minutes-for-billing

Here is another SO link regarding calculating pricing, [Twilio total call duration does not match with billing minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022950/twilio-total-call-duration-does-not-match-with-billing-minutes)

I hope this helps.